# How can I stop displaying css animations upon loading linked pages with the same header/footer?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a few simple css animations on load up of the landing page for a site. I want to move my navbar and footer to a partial and link to it on each page, but I don't want those animations to play on any page but the landing page.

This is my first time messing with css animations, so I am wondering if there is a way to include the header and footer in a partial on all the linked pages without triggering the animation.

I could redo the header and footer in a partial with separate class names so that they don't correspond to the same css, but that will add a good amount of clutter that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Maybe you could share some of you code to make it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

1. Create a separated CSS for animations and do not load it in any other page but your landing page.
2. If your animation classes are mixed with other CSS or you just want to keep them together with your main CSS, just create an exclusive class for your landing page body like "landing-with-animations" like this

```
<body class="landing-with-animations">
```

and then place your animations within this class in your CSS like

```
.landing-with-animations .animation1 {
/*rules here*/
}

.landing-with-animations .animation2{
/*rules here*/
}
```

this way, your animations only work when they are within your landing page within its body with class "landing-with animations"

Comment: Thanks Matteus! That sounds like it is the right direction.  I think I am going to create a landing page class that covers the body, header, and footer classes. I will just have to copy the header and footer without the landing page class to put in a partial. Thank you for your time!